# JavaScript/DOM - Help removing my inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Being new to JavaScript I have not been able to come up with a solution to this issue.

I want each "Add to Cart" button to invoke the same function "AddtoCart". I have achieved this but at the cost of inline JavaScript - something I would like to avoid.

`onclick=
                  "AddToCart(document.getElementById('toy_title1').innerHTML,document.getElementById('toy_quantity1').value,document.getElementById('toy_price1').innerHTML)`

So how would I achieve including this as part of the external JavaScript file, bearing in mind I have to be able to apply this to all 4 unique items

Comment: I can't find any issue, what is it exactly?

Comment: Instead of that long line of code, I would like all 4 of my buttons to only invoke "AddtoCart();" without the inline JavaScript already in place.

Comment: Oh that's what I just thought. Sorry, I didn't see any "issue" because your code is working perfectly fine and the JS/HTML isn't thrown at your end-users' face after all.

Answer (score 1):

then you should read more about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)(standard) and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(IE)

```
//assume element means the button
//you can use getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, querySelectorAll etc.
//to fetch your elements

//DRY, store the operation in a function so it's reusabe and not written twice
function thisFunction(){
    AddToCart(document.getElementById('toy_title1').innerHTML,
        document.getElementById('toy_quantity1').value,
        document.getElementById('toy_price1').innerHTML)
}

if(element.addEventListener){                      //check if the standard is supported
    element.addEventListener('click',function(){   //use it to add the handler
        thisFunction();
    });
} else {
    element.attachEvent('onclick',function(){      //else, we use IE's version
        thisFunction();
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: But the toy's ID can change, so he would need to pass parameters to the function in order to change the elements' IDs, how could he do that this way ?

Comment: @PedroSena the post did not mention, and besides, it's homework. Read the homework tag and what you should do when there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function that way:

```
function AddToCart(toyId) {
  var title = document.getElementById('toy_title'+toyId).innerHTML;
  var quantity = document.getElementById('toy_quantity'+toyId).value;
  var price = document.getElementById('toy_price')+toyId).innerHTML
}
```

Then on each button you just pass the toy's ID

Just be carefull about sensitive data like price, leaving it on Javascript(I'm supposing you will send it to your back-end after this) is dangerous, it could be easily manipulated.

But if your intention is just a test or something like that, its ok.

EDIT:
to call your this function you would do something like that:

```
onclick="AddToCart(1)"
```

Where 1 is your toy's ID, you should change it to 2,3... depending on your toy.

Comment: +1 for your speed, example and simplicity. I was going to suggest the same thing but you finished your answer before I even started :P.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, being a novice, I am not clear. :(

This is a school project so I am not concerned about sensitive data :D

Comment: What exactly is not clear ? What is being done on the function or how to call it ?

Comment: I have used that function and changed my button calls on the HTML respectively and it does not work.